# type 'List<int>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

```
      List<String> nameList,
          List<int> priceList,
          List<String> descriptionList,
          List<int> priceTypeList,
          List<double> netPriceList,
          List<double> taxList,
          List<double> nonTaxList,
          List<String> codeList,
          List<String> skuList
    
          var mapping = Map<String, dynamic>();
 mapping['variants_value[Variant][]'] = nameList == null
          ? ""
          : List<String>.from(nameList.map((String x) => x));
      mapping['name[]'] = nameList == null
          ? ""
          : List<String>.from(nameList.map((String x) => x));
      mapping['duplicate_name[]'] = nameList == null
          ? ""
          : List<String>.from(nameList.map((String x) => x));
      mapping['duplicate_ids[]'] = nameList == null
          ? ""
          : List<String>.from(nameList.map((String x) => x));
      mapping['price[]'] = priceList == null
          ? null
          : List<int>.from(priceList.map((int x) => x));
      mapping['code[]'] = descriptionList == null
          ? ""
          : List<String>.from(descriptionList.map((String x) => x));
      mapping['price_type[]'] = priceTypeList == null
          ? null
          : List<int>.from(priceTypeList.map((int x) => x));
      mapping['net_price[]'] = netPriceList == null
          ? null
          : List<double>.from(netPriceList.map((double e) => e));
      mapping['tax[]'] = taxList == null
          ? null
          : List<double>.from(taxList.map((double e) => e));
      mapping['non_tax[]'] = nonTaxList == null
          ? null
          : List<double>.from(nonTaxList.map((double e) => e));
      mapping['code_type[]'] = codeList == null
          ? ""
          : List<String>.from(codeList.map((String x) => x));
      mapping['sku[]'] = skuList == null
          ? ""
          : List<String>.from(skuList.map((String x) => x));    
     var url =
              Uri.parse('https://xyz//m/api/product/add-product');
    
          var response = await http.post(url,
              headers: {
                'Cookie': cookie,
              },
              body: mapping);
          if (response.body != null && response.statusCode == 200) {
            print(response.body);
            return response.body.toString();
          } else {
            return null;
          }
```

//Here is the params which i passed in postman

```
variants_value[Variant][]: default
name[]: default
duplicate_name[]: default
duplicate_ids[]: 
price[]: 24
code[]: fgdg
price_type[]: 0
net_price[]: 24.00
tax[]: 0.00
non_tax[]: 0
code_type[]: Others
sku[]:
```

I am passing Listvalue with the API and it's giving error that

`"type 'List<int>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast"`

Later i had passed `List<int>value.toString();` with API and i am getting the response like
`'Please enter value' Api is not accepting string` and then i have realised the value should be in the type of int

I have checked the api in postman its working fine when i pass integer value if do the same in flutter its throwing error

Please let me know how to pass List to the API

Comment: send your code to know what did you do!

Comment: @AL.Sharie please check my above edited code

Comment: show your add product code

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass like this:

```
"list": list== null ? null : List<int>.from(list.map((int x) => x)),
```

**Edit 1:** I suggest you to use [this](https://app.quicktype.io/) when there is a situation like this or in general.

Comment: type 'List<int>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast i am getting this error

Comment: I checked. You have to convert all the lists into the code that I shared. Example: Instead of ***mapping['name[]'] = nameList.toString();*** write ***mapping['name[]'] = nameList == null ? null : List<int>.from(nameList.map((int x) => x)),***

Comment: i have changed the code please check above.it doesn't helped me.After changing like this i am getting error like type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Answer (score 0):

try use

```
mapping['name'] = jsonEncode(nameList)
```

instead of using

```
mapping['name'] = List<String>.from(nameList.map((String x) => x))
```

to all of your data

according to the official doc
https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/post.html

> body sets the body of the request. It can be a String, a List or
> a Map<String, String>. If it's a String, it's encoded using encoding
> and used as the body of the request. The content-type of the request
> will default to "text/plain".

Comment: I have tried your solution i am getting response that price value is empty.because after changing to jsonencode pricelist is converted in string format but it should be an integer format

Comment: first of all do you send your data in array format `name[]` or do you send them normally `name` in postman?

Comment: try to add `headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},`

Comment: instead of using `mapping['name[]']`  use this `mapping['name']`

Comment: Bad state: Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type "application/json".
i am getting this error after setting content-type

Comment: remove the `headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}` and this error will gone

Comment: Please check my above edited code i have posted the postman params which is working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236584/discussion-between-vishali-and-al-sharie).